# SQL returning aggregated results from one table as a column in a query

Tags: sql, mysql

Say I have the following setup

```
---Posts---
|id
|Title
-----------

---Comments---
|id
|postid
|comment
-----------
```

Some Mock Data

```
Posts
ID        Title
1         Hello World
2         Good Bye
3         Pepsi

Comments
ID      postid      comment
 1        1         comment 1
 2        2         comment 2
 3        2         comment 3
```

I want to return back the Title from the Posts table and all the comments related to it via the id in the comments Table.

Something like.

```
Title           Comment
Hello World     comment1
Good Bye        comment2
                comment3
Pepsi           null
```

Is this possible just using SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Title, 
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Comment) FROM Comments
         WHERE
         Comments.postid=posts.posts) as comments
FROM posts
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select Title, Comment
 from Posts p LEFT Join Comments c on c.PostId = p.id
 Order by 1
```

However Title will be repeated, i.e. result will be:

```
 Title           Comment
 ------------------------
 Hello World     comment1
 Good Bye        comment2
 Good Bye        comment3
 Pepsi           null
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT posts.title, comments.comment 
FROM posts JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.postid

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for this:
[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)